# some issue about python socket

Tags: python, sockets

I write a example program about python socket , but I met some question when  executed the example program.

please help to  review the following code and tell me why the issue happened?  thanks!

the  issue description:
  the server socket was blocked, and just print the following info:

```
tcpServer listen at: 127.0.0.1:9003

  ('127.0.0.1', 9003)
  127.0.0.1:60541 connect
```

the client socket yet was  blocked, and did not print any info

**the code:
 server-side socket:**

```
import socket 

HOST='127.0.0.1' 
PORT=9003 
BUFFER=4096 
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind((HOST,PORT)) 

sock.listen(0) 
print('tcpServer listen at: %s:%s\n\r' %(HOST,PORT)) 


print sock.getsockname()

while True: 
    client_sock,client_addr=sock.accept() 
    print('%s:%s connect' %client_addr) 
    rf = client_sock.makefile('rb',4)
    wf = client_sock.makefile('wb',4)
    print rf.readlines()
    rf.close()
    client_sock.close()
    wf.write("from server")
    wf.flush()
    wf.close()
sock.close()
```

**and the client-side socket code:**

```
import socket 

HOST='127.0.0.1' 
PORT=9003  
BUFFER=4096 

sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
sock.connect((HOST,PORT)) 

rf = sock.makefile('rb',4)
wf = sock.makefile('wb',4)


wf.write('hello, tcpServer!') 
wf.flush()
wf.close()

recv=rf.readline()
rf.close()
print('[tcpServer said]: %s' % recv) 
sock.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server relies upon receiving an end-of-file indication, but you never send one. Try calling [`socket.shutdown()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown) in your client:

```
...
wf.write('hello, tcpServer!') 
wf.close()
sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
...
```